# Java - Airline Booking Button

Tags: java, database

I press the buttons on my Java program but it doesn't seem to do anything at all. I just press them and nothing happens. I'm using Java 8. In Eclipse.

I'm not sure if it's because there's a database connection problem? If it is I'd probably just go to SQL.

Here's the code for the Log In Page:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;  

public class login extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

JPanel pane = new JPanel();

ImageIcon imageicon =  new ImageIcon ("res/login.png");
JLabel bg = new JLabel (" ", imageicon, JLabel.CENTER); 
JLabel bg1 = new JLabel (new ImageIcon(""));


JTextField use1 = new JTextField();
JPasswordField pas1 = new JPasswordField();

JButton displayButton = new JButton("Login");
JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");

String search ="";
String searchP="";


//  Select txt2= new Select();
Connection cn;
PreparedStatement ps;
Statement st;

public login(){
    //  pane.setBackground(Color.orange);
    setContentPane (pane);
    pane.setLayout (null);

    //---------------------------------------------
    pane.add(use1);
    use1.setBounds(50,225, 190, 30);
    use1.setToolTipText("Username");

    pane.add(pas1);
    pas1.setBounds(50,260, 190, 30);
    pas1.setToolTipText("Password");
    //---------------------------------------------
    pane.add(displayButton);
    displayButton.setBounds(60,300, 80, 25);
    displayButton.addActionListener(this);


    pane.add(cancelButton);
    cancelButton.setBounds(150,300, 80, 25);
    cancelButton.addActionListener(this);

    //---------------------------------------------
    pane.add(bg1);
    bg1.setVisible(true);
    bg1.setBounds (5,40,200,129);

    pane.add(bg);
    bg.setBounds (0,0,300,400);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    try{
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://res/YOLO.accdb");
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException a){
        System.err.println("Failed to Load Driver");
        a.printStackTrace();
    }catch (SQLException a){
        System.err.println("Unable to Connect");
        a.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){

    if (e.getSource() ==displayButton){

        search=use1.getText();
        searchP=pas1.getText();


        try{    

            if (!search.equals("")||!searchP.equals("")){

                st= cn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Login WHERE UserN = '" + search+"'");

                while(rs.next()){


                    searchP=rs.getString(2);    

                    if(searchP.equalsIgnoreCase(pas1.getText())){

                        dispose();

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Login Successful!! ");
                        main frame = new main ();
                        frame.setTitle ("YOLO Airline Ticketing & Hotel Reservation");
                        frame.setBounds(200,200,800,500);
                        frame.setVisible (true);
                        frame.setResizable(false);
                        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                    }

                    st.close();
                }
            }
        }catch(SQLException m){
            System.out.println(m.getMessage());


        }finally{

            if (search.equals("")||searchP.equals("")){

                if(search.equals("")){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Input!","Warning!",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
                if(searchP.equals("")){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Password!","Warning!",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
            }



        }
    }       

}         







public static void main(String args[]) {
    login myframe = new login();
    myframe.setBounds(400,280,300,400);
    myframe.setTitle("YOLO Login");
    myframe.setVisible(true);
    myframe.setResizable(false);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
displayButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: That code is valid with no errors but does exactly the same thing, no action or messagebox appears once clicked.

Comment: None at all! The only reason I can think of is it cannot retrieve the username and password from the database, but I can't pin that error down.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, except for one statement:

> **...**
> main frame = new main ();
> **...**

I didn't see any definition for `main`, am I missing something?

Eclipse should protest against your using undefined class, don't overlook warnings, ever.